# Toggle Delphi Label color with Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

With VCL I can do this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Color := clBlue;
  Label1.Font.Color := clYellow;
  label1.Caption := ' My Label '
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Label1.Color = clBlue then
    begin
      Label1.Color := clYellow;
      Label1.Font.Color := clBlue
    end
  else
    begin
      Label1.Color := clBlue;
      Label1.Font.Color := clYellow
    end
end;
```

As you can see, the color of the label background and the text toggles from blue to yellow and vice-versa.

I want to do the same with Firemonkey but, all the search I made only says that FMX labels has no background color (I don't understand why), 
and don't give me a effetive clue how to do the same thing as in VCL.

Can someone write here the equivalent FMX code snippet?

Thank you.

Comment: FMX labels have no background color, because they are transparent. Put a control underneigh the label and change the color of whatever is underneigh the label.

Comment: @Johan: Sorry for bother you but your answer raised 2 more questions: 1) If they are transparent what's the use of the 'opacity' property? 2) How can I put a control underneath the label, programmatically (the real program what I'm develop has an array of 49 labels (7 x 7) created at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firemonkey many controls do not have a color. Instead you're supposed to layer controls out of different components.

In this case if you want a background use a `TRectangle`.
In the designer Delphi insists that you cannot have a label be parented by a rectangle, but this if of course not true, in FMX any control can parent any other.

Just use the structure pane to drag the label on top of the rectangle and voila label and rectangle are joined together.

[image]

The equivalent code to the above would look something like this.

```
unit Unit45;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Objects;

type
  TForm45 = class(TForm)
    Rectangle1: TRectangle;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Rects: array of TRectangle;
    Labels: array of TLabel;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form45: TForm45;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses
  System.UIConsts;

procedure TForm45.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i:= Low(Rects) to High(Rects) do begin
    if Rects[i].Fill.Color <> claBlue then
      Rects[i].Fill.Color:= claBlue
    else Rects[i].Fill.Color:= claYellow;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm45.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(Rects,2);
  SetLength(Labels,2);
  for i:= 0 to 1 do begin
    Rects[i]:= TRectangle.Create(self);
    Rects[i].Parent:= self;
    Labels[i]:= TLabel.Create(self);
    Labels[i].Parent:= Rects[i];
    Rects[i].Width:= Rectangle1.Width;
    Rects[i].Height:= Rectangle1.Height;
    Rects[i].Position.y:= 0 + i * Rects[i].Height;
    Rects[i].Position.x:= 0 + i * Rects[i].Width;
    Rects[i].Stroke.Kind:= TBrushKind.None;
    Labels[i].AutoSize:= true;
    Labels[i].Text:= 'Test'+IntToStr(i+1);
    Labels[i].Position:= Label1.Position;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Note that I've done the construction of the labels and rects in runtime, but you can do this in design time as well.

The color constants in FMX have changed from the VCL, see: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Colors_in_FireMonkey

Comment: Thank you Johan. Delphi is a great tool (along with C++ Builder), but deserves more books, more articles and a much more active community. It's a pity Marco Cantu doesn't write Delphi books anymore AFAIK

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can create a custom style for your TLabel component:

- right-click the Label ("LabelXX") and select "Edit Custom Style...";
- add a "TRectangle" component from the "Tool Palette" to the new style created ("LabelXXStyle1");
- select the new "Rectangle1Style" object and send it to back (Edit -> "Send to Back");

Set the "Rectangle1Style" properties:

- "Align" : "Client";
- "Fill / Bitmap / Color" : any background color;
- Apply changes (close the "Style Designer").

Set the "StyleLookup" property of the other TLabel(s) you need to "LabelXXStyle1".

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested, here is one of my samples:

```
function CreateLabel(
  AOwner: TFmxObject; ARangeWidth, ARangeHeight, ASizeMin, ASizeMax: Integer;
  AText: String; AColor: TAlphaColor): TLabel;
var
  LFMXObj: TFMXObject;
  LFontSize: Integer;
begin
  Result := TLabel.Create(AOwner);
  with Result do
  begin
    Parent := AOwner;
    Text := AText;

    ApplyStyleLookup;
    LFMXObj := FindStyleResource('text');
    if Assigned(LFMXObj) then
    begin
      LFontSize := ASizeMin + Random(ASizeMax - ASizeMin);
      //TText(LFMXObj).Fill.Color := AColor;   // XE2
      TText(LFMXObj).Color := AColor;
      TText(LFMXObj).Font.Size := LFontSize;
      TText(LFMXObj).Font.Style := TText(LFMXObj).Font.Style + [TFontStyle.fsBold];
      TText(LFMXObj).WordWrap := False;
      TText(LFMXObj).AutoSize := True;

      Canvas.Font.Assign(TText(LFMXObj).Font);
      Position.X := Random(ARangeWidth - Round(Canvas.TextWidth(Text)));
      Position.Y := Random(ARangeHeight - Round(Canvas.TextHeight(Text)));
    end;
    {
    // test background label painting
    with TRectangle.Create(Result) do
    begin
      Parent := AOwner;
      Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Lightgrey;
      Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.bkSolid;
      Width := Result.Canvas.TextWidth(Result.Text);
      Height := Result.Canvas.TextHeight(Result.Text);
      Position.X := Result.Position.X;
      Position.Y := Result.Position.Y;
      Result.BringToFront;
    end;
    }
    AutoSize := True;
    Visible := True;
  end;
end;
```